# Sharing assemblies between projects in a solution

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget

I have a **solution** that has a **project** that has a **class** that I'd like to share with another project in the same solution.

This class depends on a library that was pulled in from nuget.

Because the second project hasn't pulled this same library from nuget, the class execution fails (despite the second project depending on the first).

Up to this point, I've just been going and adding the same nuget packages to multiple projects.

This seems terribly unwieldy as when I need to update one project, I have to remember to update them all, or depend on tests, which seems like a great opportunity for bugs to slip through the cracks.

How can I go about sharing these dependencies between multiple projects in the same solution?

Comment: Right click on solution -> Manage Nuget Packages for Solution. Will allow you to install to multiple projects at same time.

Comment: The usual way to achieve that is to put your shared classes in a project of their own, and reference that project from the others.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi but my second project IS referencing my first project

Comment: @jle is that the solution?  Just tell nuget to install on every project and only ever install nuget packages at the solution level?

Comment: @SB, then I'm missing something. Unless your second project tries to access the nuget library directly, without "going through" the first project?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi no it doesn't - just a boilerplate class calling the original class.

Comment: Don't install in every project--just install in the projects that you need the packages

Comment: The Solution level nuget interface just makes it easier to do so

Comment: @jle and we arrive at the original situation

Comment: Very unclear what exactly you trying to avoid - updating all project to latest version of particular NuGet is one-click operation in VS - so unlikely you have problem with that; if code depends on assembly it had to be added to the project, there is no way around it - so again probably not that...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov the problem is that `Class1` needs `Package1` and in order to get `Project2` working with `Class1`, I have to install `Package1` on `Project2`.  Maybe I don't know that `Project2` needs `Class1` until later, so then I have to go and install the upgraded package at the solution level instead.  I don't know, maybe this is just normal process but it seems obnoxious.

Comment: Agree - if author of Class1 would be nice they would make it into NuGet and declare proper dependencies, so when you need to use Class1 all dependent NuGets are automatically added. You may want to talk to author of Class1 to consider that. (Currently projects in the same solution considered to be authored by same group of people who have reasonable communication with each other and thus let each other know what dependencies are needed. If it is not the case for you - reorganizing solution into separate once with local NuGet feed may be better option)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I'm the author of `Class1`!  How do I tell projects depending on this class to go automatically resolve dependencies?

Comment: I don't believe you can tell VS to automatically resolve dependendis unless you build and package Class1's project as separte solution producing NuGet (i.e. in you local NuGet repository). For same solution even R# does not do it correctly if dependency come from NuGet (works fine when all dependencies are from same solution).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I create a sample solution based on your description, I found the dependencies nuget library could be found automatically in other projects that reference Class1 project. But if I set the Copy to Local property as false for the nuget library in Class1 project references, I will get an error message about could not find the dependencies when running other projects.

So please check the Copy to Local property for the nuget library in your Class1 project to confirm it is set as True.

Comment: This is the answer.  Thank you.